# C++ sockets connecting to C# server

Tags: c#, c++, stream, winsock

I have a server written in C# using a TcpClient and streams. When I try to connect to it and receive data with a C++ application using Winsock, I can receive the data but it has the data but it also displays a bunch of other data. By the way I'm printing to buffer to the console using cout.

If you want to see what the server is supposed to send, go to http://onenetworks.us:12345. There the server will send you a string. For me it sends "16READY" Which is what I'm trying to get my client to only read.

[image: What is displayed when you connect.]

Here's my code, I copied a working code file off of the MSDN page.

```
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
// Link with ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "12345"

int main() {

    //----------------------
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in clientService; 

    char *sendbuf = "";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "199.168.139.14" );
    clientService.sin_port = htons( 12345 );

    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
    if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket (ConnectSocket);
        printf("Unable to connect to server: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        std::cout << recvbuf <<std::endl;
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while(iResult > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    std::cin.ignore();
    //return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your cout (here: `std::cout << recvbuf <<std::endl;`) needs to only output to a specific length because your message is not likely null terminated.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/74737-cout-fixed-length-string.html

Comment: Actually looking at your code again I'm surprised you aren't encountering more issues. Why do you shutdown the socket (and deinit winsock) before you do the recv? You could potentially end up with a race condition here.

Comment: That's just the code that was on the MSDN site.

Comment: Lesson 1 - If this could ever potentially be used in a production system, never trust MSDN examples.

Comment: One more thing... don't mix printf with cout in code examples (without good reason) you may offend some people. :)

Answer (score 1):

Print only the characters received, not the entire buffer posted. `iResult` will contain the length of the data received:

```
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
    {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        std::cout << std::string(recvbuf, recvbuf+iResult) <<std::endl;

    }
    else if ( iResult == 0 )
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of your buffer is set to DEFAULT_BUFLEN, so whatever you receive through the socket has that length. you can loop through every char of it, until a value of 0 (or '\0') is found.

Comment: The message variable isn't guaranteed to be null terminated. How does this help?

Comment: It depends on how you fill your sendbuf. for example c# string is null terminated but c++ char* is generally not. but if you use something like char* sendbuf = "some text." or fill it with a stream, it will be null terminated. Simon Mourier's answer is applicable to those cases in which you've filled the sendbuf char by char, where the receiving side doesn't know the size of the sendbuf nor where it ends.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
...
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
recvbuf[iResult] = 0; // add this to zero terminate the receive buffer
std::cout << recvbuf <<std::endl;
...
```

(of course it assumes iResult is lesser than DEFAULT_BUFLEN)